# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0. Error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to compile an old project that worked before but I'm getting an error. There are similar issues on the internet but I couldn't find the exact same issue.

Can anyone help with this problem before?

Thank you.

Visual Studio Version : 2019

Please let me know if you need more information.

***Error Message***

```
3>    Fody (version 1.28.3.0) Executing
3>MSBUILD : error : Fody: An unhandled exception occurred:
3>MSBUILD : error : Exception:
3>MSBUILD : error : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
3>MSBUILD : error : StackTrace:
3>MSBUILD : error : 
3>MSBUILD : error : Server stack trace: 
3>MSBUILD : error :    at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
3>MSBUILD : error :    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()
3>MSBUILD : error :    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParameters()
3>MSBUILD : error :    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
3>MSBUILD : error : 
3>MSBUILD : error : Exception rethrown at [0]: 
3>MSBUILD : error :    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
3>MSBUILD : error :    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
3>MSBUILD : error :    at IInnerWeaver.set_Logger(ILogger value)
3>MSBUILD : error :    at Processor.ExecuteInOwnAppDomain() in c:\ConsoleBuildAgent\work\ed448661dbb30d2e\Fody\Processor.cs:line 146
3>MSBUILD : error :    at Processor.Inner() in c:\ConsoleBuildAgent\work\ed448661dbb30d2e\Fody\Processor.cs:line 93
3>MSBUILD : error :    at Processor.Execute() in c:\ConsoleBuildAgent\work\ed448661dbb30d2e\Fody\Processor.cs:line 45
3>MSBUILD : error : Source:
3>MSBUILD : error : mscorlib
3>MSBUILD : error : TargetSite:
3>MSBUILD : error : Void GetSignature(Void*, Int32, System.RuntimeFieldHandleInternal, System.IRuntimeMethodInfo, System.RuntimeType)
3>MSBUILD : error : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
3>MSBUILD : error : StackTrace:
3>MSBUILD : error : 
3>MSBUILD : error :
```

Comment: You saw the "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0" ?  Do you have .net 4.0.0 on that computer?  IIRC later versions of net 4.x overwrite in place. You're likely to have 4.8

Comment: Have you checked your project folder, whether exists a file name like "FodyWeavers.xml"? If yes, fody settings must be fullfilled.

Comment: Yes, there was FodyWeavers.xml file. It was empty and unused. I deleted it. I removed the nuget package it depends on and the problem was solved. Thank you.